# Forward selected emails without non-PDF attachments

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to send a completed work email containing multiple PDF attachments, I wish send only the PDF files to the recipient and avoid any other atttachments such as excel files or image files only pdf to be forwarded.

P.S. note email may have more than 1 attachments with combination of pdfs, excels, images, however only pdfs have to be forwarded. I'm unable to find how to code that part. please see below my existing code.

```
        Sub Send2Recipient()

        ' Send Completed Message to Recipient

        On Error Resume Next

        Dim oApp As Outlook.Application
        Dim objFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
        Set oApp = New Outlook.Application
        Set objNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
        Set objInbox = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
        Set objFolder = objInbox.Folders("Helpdesk")
        Dim oEmail As Outlook.MailItem
        Dim strFile As String
        Dim sFileType As String

        'Require that this procedure be called only when a message is selected
        If Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count = 0 Then
            Exit Sub
        End If

        For Each objItem In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
            If objFolder.DefaultItemType = olMailItem Then
                If objItem.Class = olMail Then
                    Response = MsgBox("Forward message (" + item.Subject + ") to Appended Subject")

                    Set myforward = objItem.Forward
                    myforward.Body = "Scan Only"
                    myforward.Subject = "Scan Only"
                    myforward.Recipients.Add "DHL.GB01PREV@dhl.com"
                    myforward.Display
                End If
            End If
        Next

        End Sub
```

---

Updated VBA script

```
        Sub Send2New()

        ' Send Completed Message to Accenture

        On Error Resume Next

        Dim oApp As Outlook.Application
        Dim objFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
        Set oApp = New Outlook.Application
        Set objNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
        Set objInbox = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
        'Set objFolder = objInbox.Folders("Helpdesk")
        Dim oEmail As Outlook.MailItem
        Dim strFile As String
        Dim sFileType As String
        Dim bk, fg As Integer

        'Require that this procedure be called only when a message is selected
        If Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count = 0 Then
            Exit Sub
        End If

        For Each objItem In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
            If objFolder.DefaultItemType = olMailItem Then
                If objItem.Class = olmail Then
                    Response = MsgBox("Forward message (" + Item.Subject + ") to Appended Subject")

                    Set myforward = objItem.Forward
                    myforward.Body = "Scan Only"
                    myforward.Subject = "Scan Only"
                    myforward.Recipients.Add "xyz@abc.com"
                    myforward.Display

                    bk = myforward.Attachments.Count
                    fg = 1
                    For i = 1 To bk
                        If InStr(LCase(myforward.Attachments(fg).FileName), ".pdf") = 0 Then
                            myforward.Attachments(fg).Delete
                            Else: fg = fg + 1
                        End If
                    Next i

                    End If
            End If
        Next

        End Sub
```

Comment: You seem to have deleted your previous question.  In a comment, I linked to an earlier answer that showed how to identify the attachments to an email;.  I can give you the link again if necessary. I do not believe it is possible to move attachments from one email to another.  You could save (to disc) the attachments from the old email then attach them to the new email. Alternatively, you could duplicate the old email, delete the unwanted attachments and replace sender, recipient and body.  I confess I have never done all of that in one go but the individual steps are not difficult.

Comment: Thank you so much for the info Tony, yes I deleted the other question as it was related to outlook to excel report, this is more to do with forwarding the existing email to a fixed email address and having only pdf attachments, if it has other attachments, those should not be forwarded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created two macros for you.

The first, `Investigate`, outputs information about attachments to the Immediate Window.  There are four types of attachment.  A “standard” attachment is of type “By Value”.  I have never seen an OLE attachment and do not know what such an attachment is.  I have seen the other types but not for many years.

The second, `ForwardEmailsWithoutNonPdfAttachments()`, demonstrates the functionality you seek.  I have sent emails containing a selection of attachments from my Gmail account to my Outlook account and have used the macro to send them back with the non-PDF attachments deleted.  These attachments were all “By Value” attachments.  I am not sure what would happen if you tried to forward emails with other types of attachments which is the reason for the first macro.  This macro is not very elegant but it demonstrates the techniques necessary to meet your objective.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Investigate()

  Dim AttachType As String
  Dim Exp As Outlook.Explorer
  Dim InxAttach As Long
  Dim ItemCrnt As MailItem
  Dim NumAttach As Long
  Dim NumSelected As Long

  Set Exp = Outlook.Application.ActiveExplorer

  NumSelected = Exp.Selection.Count

  If NumSelected = 0 Then
    Debug.Print "No emails selected"
  Else
    For Each ItemCrnt In Exp.Selection
      With ItemCrnt
        Debug.Print "From: " & .SenderName & " | Subject: " & .Subject
        For InxAttach = 1 To .Attachments.Count
          ' There are four types of attachment:
          '  *   olByValue       1
          '  *   olByReference   4
          '  *   olEmbeddedItem  5
          '  *   olOLE           6
          With .Attachments(InxAttach)
            Select Case .Type
              Case olByValue
               AttachType = "Val"
              Case olEmbeddeditem
                AttachType = "Ebd"
              Case olByReference
                AttachType = "Ref"
              Case olOLE
                AttachType = "OLE"
              Case Else
                AttachType = "Unk"
            End Select
            Debug.Print AttachType & " " & .FileName & " | " & .DisplayName
          End With  ' .Attachments(InxAttach)
        Next  ' ItemCrnt
      End With
    Next
  End If

End Sub
Sub ForwardEmailsWithoutNonPdfAttachments()

  Dim AttachType As String
  Dim Exp As Outlook.Explorer
  Dim InxAttach As Long
  Dim ItemCopy As MailItem
  Dim ItemOrig As MailItem
  Dim NumAttach As Long
  Dim NumSelected As Long

  Set Exp = Outlook.Application.ActiveExplorer

  NumSelected = Exp.Selection.Count

  If NumSelected = 0 Then
    Debug.Print "No emails selected"
  Else
    For Each ItemOrig In Exp.Selection

      Set ItemCopy = ItemOrig.Copy
      With ItemCopy
        .Subject = "FW: " & .Subject
        ' Delete all original recipients
        Do While .Recipients.Count > 0
          .Recipients.Remove (1)
        Loop
        ' Add new recipient
        .Recipients.Add "tonydallimore23@gmail.com"
        If .Attachments.Count > 0 Then
          For InxAttach = .Attachments.Count To 1 Step -1
            With .Attachments(InxAttach)
              ' This will stop the macro if an attachment is not a regular attachment
              Debug.Assert .Type = olByValue
              If LCase(Right$(.FileName, 4)) <> ".pdf" Then
                .Delete
              End If
            End With  ' .Attachments(InxAttach)
          Next InxAttach
        End If
        .Send
      End With  ' ItemCopy
      Set ItemCopy = Nothing
    Next ItemOrig
  End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Tony, I tried the above provided macros, They work Perfect, I had made some changes for the body and the subject as per the requirements :) , only one question is that , it doesn't forward the existing email, so I am unable to determine if it has been worked upon, Great Help Thank you Tony :)

Comment: @PawanTejani  My standard technique is to move processed emails to another folder.  I do not normally use Explorer.  I normally search Inbox for emails of interest, process them and then move them to the archive folder.  As an alternative, there should be a copy of the forwarded email in Sent Items.

Comment: Let me explain the situation, these emails are on a huge 250GB shared mailbox, hence I'm avoiding creating more copies, I rather prefer forwarding the same email as other users get to see the specific email being actioned.

Comment: Even if you do not change the subject or the title, you are creating a new email with a new sender, recipients and sent time.  I do not believe you can avoid a copy of the new email being saved in Sent Items.  I do not like deleting from Sent Items immediately.  You could have a macro that searches Sent Items for the previous day's emails and deletes them perhaps after adding a record to an Excel workbook.

Comment: Hi Tony, Thank you for the help, my concern is that it doesn't remove the From Field ( original sender's email ) and reflect my name as I'm sending the email now.  can you check on this part.

Comment: In my experiments, the sender value is unchanged when an email is forwarded.  Does something different happen on your system?

Comment: the original email doesn't show that it has been forwarded, like it would show ,as the above macro creates a copy of it. so that is my concern. if you could advise of a fix it will be a life saver.

Comment: In my macro, I have the statement `.Subject = "FW: " & .Subject` which adds "FW: " to the beginning of the subject in the same way as happens if you manually forward an email.  Have you amended or removed this statement?

Comment: Hi Tony,  yes because I have a dedicated subject to be sent to the recipients email address,  I will take a screenshot tomorrow morning to show you what I wish to achieve as I understand that the macro we are using now creates a copy of the existing email and then sends it

Comment: the solution that finally works for me is as below :) thank you for your help I know i'm posting too late but this works best